# Loopback combining filter with where condition and order by

Tags: loopbackjs

My model Person has `FirstName`, `LastName`, `PersonId`, `roleid`, `CreatedDate`, `OrderDate`

My Query is:

> http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/persons?filter={"where":{"and":[{"roleid":"2"},{"personid":{"inq":["1","2","3"]}}]}}

I am able to retrieve the results, but the order of results is coming randomly.

Any way to order the results by a `createddate asc`, `orderdate desc`?

I am not able combine the where and order by filters using `and`.

Comment: I went with an alternate approach which works for me currenly,added a "scope" property in the person.json model definition to add default order {"sort":{"order":"createddate"}}

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
{
  "where":{"and":[{"roleid":"2"},{"personid":{"inq":["1","2","3"]}}]},
  "order": "orderdate DESC",
}
```

or if you want to order by multiple properties you can use:

```
{
  "where":{"and":[{"roleid":"2"},{"personid":{"inq":["1","2","3"]}}]},
  "order": ["orderdate DESC", "createddate ASC"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `&filter[order][0]=CreatedDate&filter[order][1]=orderdate&20desc`.

Comment: `{"where":{"and":[{"personid":"211"},{"roleid":{"inq":["1","2","3"]}}]}}` is my current URL on which i do a HTTP GET.. when i add a new filter as you mentioned above, fails with   400 Value is not an object.

Comment: Oh sorry - you are using the JSON format of the parameter and I was using the - well non JSON format. If you switch your format to mine it may work - about to get into a meeting so will return later.

Comment: If you add a comma before the final } and then do: {"order":["CreatedData","orderdate desc"]} does that work?